# In an sbt 0.13.7 project, compile the compiler-interfaces without compiling the project code

Tags: scala, sbt

In a freshly checked out sbt ( 0.3.7 ) project and empty ivy cache, is it possible to trigger compilation of the compiler-interface(s) needed without compiling the project itself? I have poked around but haven't found a way.

Currently if a compiler-interface is required it will be created during compilation of the project. I would like to have this compiled directly in a separate command if possible. This would allow CircleCi to cache it saving 1-3 minutes with every build because it could be cached in the dependencies section of the circle.yml.

Answer (score 0):

In sbt 0.13.12 `compile:compileIncremental` seems to do the trick. I ran `inspect compile` and inspected its dependencies to find the command.